# Bundle command not found while deploying rails app in aws using mina

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, amazon-web-services, deployment

While deploying my rails app using mina, I have got error like `bash: line 82: bundle: command not found`. I have googled but I could not find any solutions. How do I fix this?

This is my deploy.rb

```
require 'mina/bundler'
require 'mina/rails'
require 'mina/git'


set :user, 'ubuntu'
set :domain, 'www.fuitter.com'
set :deploy_to, '/usr/share/nginx/html/fuitter'
set :repository, 'git@bitbucket.org:mc_cannibal/fuitter2.git'
set :branch, 'master'
set :forward_agent, true


set :shared_paths, ['config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', 'log']


task :environment do
  ruby_version = File.read('.ruby-version').strip
  raise "Couldn't determine Ruby version: Do you have a file .ruby-version in your project root?" if ruby_version.empty?
  queue %{
    source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
    rvm use #{ruby_version} || exit 1
  }
end

task :setup => :environment do
  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/log"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/log"]

  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config"]

  # Add the repository server to .ssh/known_hosts
  if repository
    repo_host = repository.split(%r{@|://}).last.split(%r{:|\/}).first
    repo_port = /:([0-9]+)/.match(repository) && /:([0-9]+)/.match(repository)[1] || '22'

    queue! %[
      if ! ssh-keygen -H  -F #{repo_host} &>/dev/null; then
        ssh-keyscan -t rsa -p #{repo_port} -H #{repo_host} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      fi
    ]
  end

  # Create database.yml for Postgres if it doesn't exist
  path_database_yml = "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
  database_yml = %[production:
  database: fuitter
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000]
  queue! %[ test -e #{path_database_yml} || echo "#{database_yml}" > #{path_database_yml} ]

  # Create secrets.yml if it doesn't exist
  path_secrets_yml = "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml"
  secret =
  secrets_yml = %[production:
  secret_key_base:
    #{`rake secret`.strip}]
  queue! %[ test -e #{path_secrets_yml} || echo "#{secrets_yml}" > #{path_secrets_yml} ]

  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx,o-rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config"]

end

desc "Deploys the current version to the server."
task :deploy => :environment do
  to :before_hook do
    # Put things to run locally before ssh
  end
  deploy do
    # Put things that will set up an empty directory into a fully set-up
    # instance of your project.
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
    invoke :'deploy:cleanup'

    to :launch do
      #queue "service #{user} restart"
    end
  end
end
```

Should I push the deploy.rb file in version control?
PS I have rvm installed.

Comment: Do you have bundler installed on the server for the Ruby version that you're using?

Comment: @p4sh4 yes, I have installed bundler in the server. I have tried again and still the error persist.

Comment: Are you sure you've installed it for the same version of Ruby on the server that's defined in your local `.ruby-version`?

Comment: @p4sh4, yes. When I run `cat .ruby-version` in my local machine I got 2.2.3. I ran `ruby -v` on the server and got `ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]` . Does it make a difference?

Comment: The patch (p173) version may make a difference, but I doubt it's the issue here. Check your Ruby versions installed on the server, and if you have two or more 2.2.3s with different patch versions. When you run `gem list` on the server, do you see `bundler` there? It could also be an RVM gemset issue, which I'd suggest to resolve by not using RVM and using rbenv instead :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I have fixed it. I had put the wrong rvm path. After running `which rvm` , I copied that path and pasted it here.

```
 task :environment do
  ruby_version = File.read('.ruby-version').strip
  raise "Couldn't determine Ruby version: Do you have a file .ruby-version in your project root?" if ruby_version.empty?
  queue %{
    source path/to/rvm
    rvm use #{ruby_version} || exit 1
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the rvm with this configuration

```
task :environment do
  # If you're using rbenv, use this to load the rbenv environment.
  # Be sure to commit your .ruby-version or .rbenv-version to your repository.
  # invoke :'rbenv:load'

  # For those using RVM, use this to load an RVM version@gemset.
  invoke :'rvm:use', 'ruby-x.x.x'
end
```